# Python Scipy count Labels wrapping

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, counting

I know that `Scipy`'s `ndimage` has a [label counting function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html), but I'd like to count them in a `wrapping mode` (as if the image was on the surface of a sphere, where you leave an array on one side and enter it again on the opposite side, modulo in both index directions) and it doesn't seem to provide the option for such parameters.

Is there a function for such label counting in `Scipy` or `Numpy` (since I want to do it on an `ndarray` of booleans)? If there is not, is there maybe an easy workaround or way to implement it using the existing functions?

Background is the following: I want to count objects in a game of life implementation and my implementation allows `wrapping mode` or `non-wrapping mode`. So if there is wrapping mode enabled, the counting of objects should also be wrapping. Wrapping mode for calculating the next state in game of life is implemented with the `2dconvolve` function of `Scipy`.